# How to request access code & token C# Oath2.0

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0, authorization, postman

sample URL:   [https://test.test.com/services/data,\n](https://test.test.com/services/data,%5Cn)

In postman when I click on **get new access token** , [image: i feed callback URL,authorize url,accesstokenurl,clientID,clientSecID, Granttype:]

when I click on request token i get a popup window to login using username,password.then it is never required after 1 time OTP verification. finally the token is used and with RAW body data , i fetch url and it responds back with 200 status code. how to do programmatically the *request token* part in c# ?

As far as I got Oath2.0, it fetches a URL for auth code=> use that code to get access token=> finally use post url with token to work.

When I click on Code in postman it Generated code for C# - RestSharp. Now that is the scenario when token is already present. Is there something same for request token part as well ?

With the generated code I can see something like this :

```
request.AddHeader("Cookie", "BrowserId=RtFiu8ysE; BrowserId_sec=RtFiu8y; rememberUn=true; login=c3Jpc3JpLm; com.xxxxxxxx.LocaleInfo=us; oinfo=xxxxxxxxx=; autocomplete=1; oid=xxxxxxxxx; webact=%7B%22l_vdays%22%3A1%2C%22l_visit%22%3A1xxxxxxxxx3%2C%22session%22%3Axxxxxxxxx448%2C%22l_search%22%3A%22%22%2C%22l_dtype%22%3A%22%22%2C%22l_page%22%3A%22SFDC%3Aus%3Alogin%3Adeveloper%22%2C%22counter%22%3A3%2C%22pv%22%3A1%2C%22f_visit%22%3Axxxxxxxxx682%2C%22seg%22%3A%22non-customer%3Aus%22%2C%22developer%22%3Axxxxxxxxx43%7D; sfdc_lv2=xxxxxxxxxnx/Slxxxxxxxxxg+aoxxxxxxxxxJmq/6lDwolM=");
```

So for these values like browserId, login, oinfo, oid etc. how will I be able to get in c# ?

basically, how does this work ? like for getting auth code do i need to make httprequest? which url should i be hitting first ? callback or authorize ?
as per their doc: they say to fetch :`https://xxx.xxx.com/services/oauth2/authorize? client_id=xxxxxxx& redirect_uri=https://www.xxxxxx.com/oauth2/callback& response_type=code`
and then

```
https://www.xxxxx.com/oauth2/callback? code=tesauthcodexxxx
```

and then

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 Host: xxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com Content-length: 307 Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded grant_type=authorization_code& code=xxxxxxx& client_id=xxxxxxx& client_secret=*******& redirect_uri=https://www.xxxxxx.com/oauth2/callback
```

i checked a number of posts to use Oath2.0 but everywhere they say they already have token [but then how to get auth code].

I am new to Oath2.0. I know i am missing a lot on understanding concept but sometimes delivery is on the head with new people. sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the support from the auth server (but i'm assuming they're fully OATH2 compliant), have a look at [The IdentityModel Package](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel) for C#. It will save you a ton of time trying to reinvent the wheel yourself. With the given documentation, you could have this up and running in a couple of minutes.